# Doubly circular linked list leaving trailing 0 at the end when deleting a node from start

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

Can somebody please specify why this `deleteB` function is leaving a trailing 0 at the end after deleting. I tried this method out of curiosity.

I tried to access the previous pointer of head and making it's next pointer point to `head->next` instead of `head`.

After that I am changing the previous pointer of `head->next` and make it point to `head->prev` instead of `head`.

Finally I `free` the `temp` after changing the `head`.

Maybe method is wrong...Guide me if am wrong.

[image: this is the output given by the code posted below]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void deleteB(Node **head)
{
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
        if ((*head)->next == *head)
        {
            *head = NULL;
            return;
        }
        Node *temp = *head;
        (*head)->prev->next = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next->prev = (*head)->prev;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
        // Node *curr = *head;
        // while (curr->next != *head)
        // {
        //  curr = curr->next;
        // }
        // curr->next = (*head)->next;
        // (*head)->next->prev = curr;
        // *head = (*head)->next;
        // free(temp);
    }
}

void prepend(Node **head, int value)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->data = value;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
        (*head)->next = *head;
        (*head)->prev = *head;
        return;
    }
    Node *temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != *head)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = temp;
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
}

void append(Node **head, int value)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->data = value;
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = newNode;
        (*head)->next = *head;
        (*head)->prev = *head;
        return;
    }
    Node *temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != *head)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
    newNode->prev = temp;
    newNode->next = *head;
}

void display(Node *head)
{
    printf("\nPrinting the list: ");
    Node *temp = head;
    do
    {
        printf("-->%d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    } while (temp != head);
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    append(&head, 1);
    append(&head, 2);
    append(&head, 3);
    append(&head, 4);
    // insertAtN(&head, 9, 1);
    deleteB(&head);
    display(head);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `append` function you have missed `(*head)->prev = newNode`. It is true for `prepend` function as well.
[DEMO](https://onlinegdb.com/YucOT9S82)

Comment: For you next question: don't put all of your text in bold face, it defies the purpose of bold face. Also don't post pictures of text. Your output is text. Post text as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting a node in a (non-empty, circular) doubly linked list, there are 4 pointers to set. Two pointing away from the new node, and two pointing *to* it. You missed one of the latter two:

```
(*head)->prev = newNode;
```

Some other remarks:

- `prepend` has the same code as `append`, with just one more statement following it. So avoid code repetition, and let `prepend` call `append`.
- Create a separate function just for constructing the new node
- Don't initialise the `prev` and `next` members as `NULL`, since that is *never* the value they should have in a circular list. Why not initialise them with a self reference... then there is at least a chance this will be the final value, and you'll never have to check if their value is `NULL`.
- In `append` (and `prepend`) there is no good reason why you should walk with `temp` forward along all the nodes of the list in order to find the last node, when you have a *direct* reference from the head node to that tail node! (`prev`)
- [Don't cast the value returned by `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- `display` will have undefined behaviour when passing it an empty list. So add a guard.

Updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void deleteB(Node **head)
{
    if (*head != NULL)
    {
        if ((*head)->next == *head)
        {
            *head = NULL;
            return;
        }
        Node *temp = *head;
        (*head)->prev->next = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next->prev = (*head)->prev;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

// Separate function, just to construct a node
Node *newNode(int value) 
{
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // Don't cast
    node->prev = node; // Circular list never has NULL here, so don't put it
    node->next = node;
    node->data = value;
    return node;
}

void append(Node **head, int value)
{
    Node *node = newNode(value);
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        *head = node;
        return;
    }
    // We can find the tail with one step
    Node *tail = (*head)->prev;
    tail->next = node;
    node->prev = tail;
    node->next = *head;
    (*head)->prev = node; // This was missing
}

void prepend(Node **head, int value)
{
    append(head, value); // Code reuse
    *head = (*head)->prev;
}

void display(Node *head)
{
    printf("Printing the list: ");
    if (head == NULL) // Guard!
    { 
       return;
    }
    Node *temp = head;
    do
    {
        printf("-->%d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    } while (temp != head);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    append(&head, 1);
    append(&head, 2);
    append(&head, 3);
    append(&head, 4);
    deleteB(&head);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```